# What does this typescript scheme mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What does this typescript scheme mean?

```
  interface Validator<T extends FormControl> {
     (c:T): {[error: string]:any};
  }
```

I'm a bit new to Typescript and I'm trying to understand this interface function. In particular, what does the `<T extends FormControl>` represent?

And what `{[error: string]:any}` signify? My guess is the return object of the function is an object with a key of type 'string' and a value of 'any' type. Can someone help clarify?

Comment: `<T extends FormControl>` is a way to display `generic` class whose type extends `FormControl`

Answer (score 2):

> what does the `T extends FormControl` represent

This is [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). Basically the `<T extends FormControl>` introduces a new type `T` that should be the subtype of `FormControl` type.

The `Validator` is a function that takes an object of any type that is a subtype of `FormControl`, including `FormControl` type.

> what `{[error: string]:any}` signify?

It specifies a new [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) with properties of string type.